# I am using BeautifulSoup and i want to get img tag's alt value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get opposing team of one baseball team's today's game.

So I coded this.

This code get today's game's information from Web site.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.Request("http://www.hanwhaeagles.co.kr/html/game/1st_schedule_list1.asp")
data = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

bs = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

l = bs.find_all('div')
idx = 0

for s in l:
    try:
        prop = s.get('class')
        if prop != None and prop[0] == "box" and len(prop) == 2:
            l = s
            break
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print("Error")
    finally:
        idx += 1

print(l)
```

and 'variable l' is today's game's information.

img tag's alt value is opposing team's team name.

I want to print it... Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are more interested in data which exist inside `box` class. You can directly extract that class and further process it :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.Request("http://www.hanwhaeagles.co.kr/html/game/1st_schedule_list1.asp")
data = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
bs = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for item in bs.select('.box'):
    team_name = item.find('img')['alt']
    print(team_name)

'NC'
'NC'
...
```

Comment: team_name = chunck[0].find('img')['alt']
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: and I printed chuck, it's value is []

Comment: I have edited the answer according to your code, now try

Comment: Thank you. Now I know select method.

Comment: Today's game is .box.today   so I edit bs.select('.box')  to bs.select('.box.today'), I resolve this problem.

Comment: Your Welcome @황준필 :) , and if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.Request("http://www.hanwhaeagles.co.kr/html/game/1st_schedule_list1.asp")
data = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

bs = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

table = bs.find('table')

for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        if td.find('img'):
            if 'alt' in td.find('img').attrs:
                print(td.find('img')['alt'])
```

output:

```
NC
NC
NC
KIA
KIA
KIA
두산
두산
삼성
삼성
넥센
넥센
SK
SK
NC
NC
롯데
롯데
KT
KT
KIA
KIA
SK
SK
LG
LG
KT
```

Comment: I did it. Thanks!